# Embed [WP]RoyalSlider on Homepage

Tags: wordpress

I Read all Document from RoyalSlider Wordpress Plugin and search on google.

But I Can't UnderStand how to embed RoyalSlider on website homepage

I'm copy `<?php register_new_royalslider_files(1); ?>` on `function.php`

But how to located RoyalSlider on `index.php` and how to add image to that?

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: no, sorry. I had to use another plugin.
i can't import any image or gallery to that,so i decide use `smart-slider` instead .but 1+ for your help.

Comment: In general to add a plugin to your homepage you just need to add `<php echo do_shortcode('[someshortcode]'); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

In the php page, put the following code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[new_royalslider id="1"]');?>
```

Change `id=1` to the id of your slider.